# Invert directory structure

Tags: command-line, directory

I made a horrible error in a very long-running computation.

One part of the computation stores result files in a directory structure like so:

```
path/to/first/[A,B,C,D]/[1,2,3,4,5]/outfiles
```

And another does it like this:

```
path/to/second/[1,2,3,4,5]/[A,B,C,D]/outfiles
```

That is, when part 1 of the script stores files, it creates a directory for, say, A, then stores iterations 1,2,3,4, and 5 as subdirectories. When part 2 does its computations, it creates a directory for iteration 1, and then stores the first iteration of computations A,B,C, and D in subdirectories.

I'd like to "invert" the second directory structure to be like the first, since rerunning the original script with the directory fix will take too long, and my post-processing code that should otherwise work for part 2 already handles part 1's structure.

That is, `path/to/second/1/A` should become `path/to/second/A/1`, containing the files that were previously `1/A`. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

To complicate matters with making temporary directories, while I used [A,B,C,D]  and [1,2,3,4,5] in my example for clarity, the directories for both hierarchies are just numbers and  definitely have name collisions (that is, things like `10/10` exist).

Comment: Practical question: do you have enough disk space to create a temporary directory? Furthermore: in the last directory, are there more then 26 dirs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is actually to rename all dirs named with an integer, by a capital with the corresponding index(+1) from the alphabet, and vice versa:

```
1 -> A
```

while e.g.

```
C -> 3
```

Assuming you have no more than 26 folders on a level (number of letters in the alphabet) , the question is not *that* complicated, but we need to take into account a few things:

1. We need to rename the directories *from bottom to top*, since moving directories inside meanwhile renamed directories will fail.
2. Since you mention possible name clashes, we need to do the renaming in *two runs*:

   1. rename the dirs, adding a non-sense, unique string to prevent name clashes
   2. remove the string after all renaming took place

That is exactly what the script below does:

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import string
import shutil
import os
import sys

reorg = sys.argv[1]

chars = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
nums = [str(i+1) for i, c in enumerate(chars)]

tempstring = "_temp1234"

# first step: rename from bottom to top
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(reorg, topdown = False):
    for dr in dirs:
        tempname = None
        if dr in chars:
            tempname = str(chars.index(dr)+1)+tempstring
        elif dr in nums:
            tempname = chars[nums.index(dr)]+tempstring
        if tempname:
             print(dr, tempname)
             shutil.move(root+"/"+dr, root+"/"+tempname)

# second step: remove the temporary string
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(reorg, topdown = False):
    for dr in dirs:
        if tempstring in dr:
            shutil.move(root+"/"+dr, root+"/"+dr.replace(tempstring, ""))
```

#### To use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `reorg.py`
2. Run it with the targeted directory as argument:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/reorg.py /path/to/second
   ```

As always, please first try on a sample.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want in bash:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p /path-to-second-new/{A,B,C,D}
for i in [1,2,3,4,5]
do 
    for j in [A,B,C,D]
    do
        cp -v /path-to-second/"$i"/"$j" /path-to-second-new/"$j"/"$i"
    done
done
```

Your normal structure should then be in `/path-to-second-new/` and your initial structure untouched in `/path-to-second/`.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem recently in a situation where it was not practical to list all folders manually. Wanting to use a bash script, I came up with the following:

```
for a in */; do
    for b in $a/*/; do
        dir=${b##*//}
        mkdir -p $dir$a
        mv $a$dir* $dir$a
    done
    rm -rf $a
done
```

This dynamically grabs the folder names, creates the new hierarchy, moves all files and removes the old folders.

Extracting the second-level folder uses a bit of a hack. All directory names `$a` will end in `/` (e.g. `folder1/`). In the second for-loop I append another slash after `$a` (the first `/` in `$a/*/`), so each entry `$b` will look like `folder1//folder2/`. This double slash is ignored by Unix, so I can filter out the directory name by cutting away everything up to and including this double slash with `dir=${b##*//}`.